# CouchDB - requesting _config and _log gives 404

Tags: couchdb

Previously before couchdb 2.0, I can access `_config` and `_log`. But now, accessing those paths give me `404` and if I enable authentication those paths give `401` without authentication and `404` with authentication. [The docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/server/configuration.html#get--_config) doesn't say anything about changes on this. So, why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turned out that `_config` can be accessed from `/_node/couchdb@localhost/_config`. The `couchdb@localhost` part can be seen in `/_membership`.

Comment: fwiw, this was mentioned on the [What's New](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/whatsnew/2.0.html) page, but that's admittedly obscure and should be in the documentation proper. (which is probably what they mean by "forthcoming")

Comment: If you want an advice, you can take a look at the [couchdb-documentation sources](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-documentation) which sometimes, contains updated documentation.